# не могу авторизоваться в lavarel после переделки на jwt

Tags: php, laravel

Проект создал на Laravel 8.0.
С помощью этой команды сделал стандартную авторизацию.

composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui vue --auth
сделал изменения -добавил jwt руководствуясь этой инструкцией. Проверил в postman - там все работает. Токен приходит и авторизация  и регистрация работает.
После чего зарегистрировался в проекте. Запись в таблице БД создалась. После чего пробую авторизироваться на странице /login. Происходит следующее: Контроллер Login отрабатывает нормально и перенаправляет на контроллер /home. Вот только я снова попадаю на страницу login

у контроллера прописал $this->middleware('auth');
Подскажите,пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

api.php

```
 <?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;
use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;

Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'auth'
], function () {
    Route::post('login', 'App\Http\Controllers\AuthController@login');


Route::post('registration', 'App\Http\Controllers\AuthController@registration');
Route::post('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
Route::post('refresh', 'AuthController@refresh');
Route::post('me', 'AuthController@me');
```

});

```
HomeController.php

    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    
  public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
```

Comment: Проверьте настройки хранилища сессии в .env и конф. файлах, возможно сессия не сохраняется после ввода авторизационных данных. Так же возможно есть путанница в то что у вас auth:api (что для API, а не для Web) а не просто auth

Comment: @Daniel Protopopov, спасибо за помощь. Сессии действительно не сохраняются. А что в этом случае нужно делать? Буду рад ответу.

Comment: Проверьте их настройки в .env и конфигурационных файлах, в частности их драйвер для сохранения (memcache, file ...)